# stuck on Cannot implicitly convert type 'OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver' to 'OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver' after update to selenium 4

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, upgrade

Recently updated my project to use selenium 4 from selenium 3 and just running into the issue of Cannot implicitly convert type 'OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome.ChromeDriver' to 'OpenQA.Selenium.Remote.RemoteWebDriver' after the update, I've included the code below if anyone knows how to fix this

```
using System;
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Firefox;
using OpenQA.Selenium.IE;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Remote;

namespace MyProj.Selenium.Core
{
    public enum BrowserEnum
    {
        Chrome,
        IE,
        FireFox
    }

    public static class WebDriverManager
    {
        public static RemoteWebDriver CreateWebDriver(bool headlessMode, BrowserEnum browser)
        {
            switch (browser)
            {

                case BrowserEnum.Chrome:
                    var options = new ChromeOptions();
                    //Disables warning that chrome is being used by automated software
                    options.AddArgument("disable-infobars");
                    if (!headlessMode)
                    {
                        options.AddArguments("--disable-features=VizDisplayCompositor");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        options.AddArgument("--headless");
                    }
               
                    options.AddArgument("no-sandbox");
                    var driver = new ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService.CreateDefaultService(), options, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(3));
                    driver.SetPageLoadTimeout(300);
                    return driver;

                case BrowserEnum.FireFox:
                    return new FirefoxDriver();
                case BrowserEnum.IE:
                    return new InternetExplorerDriver();
                default:
                    throw new InvalidOperationException();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried looking at documentation and nothing really seems to address this issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Selenium 4.0 changed to the newer WebDriver class from the prior IWebDriver interface. It has new Dom level methods and other new functionality. It also inherits from IWebDriver but does not allow even a downcast to IWebDriver followed by an upcast to RemoteWebDriver; much less just a cast to RemoteWebDriver.

Perhaps it was by design, but smells like a bug because RemoteWebDriver also inherits from IWebDriver.

You can get a RemoteWebDriver by newing one up using a current IWebDriver. Not optimal, but it works.

You can also create Extension methods for WebDriver types; which emulate a RemoteWebDriver.

I think someone should create a bug on this.

Comment: "You can get a RemoteWebDriver by newing one up using a current IWebDriver. Not optimal, but it works." Can you give code example how to do it?

Answer (score -1):

I think your method is expecting to get back a RemoteWebDriver when you are returning a Chromedriver or IWebDriver. Try changing

```
public static RemoteWebDriver
```

To

```
public static IWebDriver
```

This works for me:

```
        public static IWebDriver InitBrowser(string browserName)
        {

            switch (browserName)
            {
                case "chrome":
                    {
                        //"--auto-open-devtools-for-tabs",
                        ChromeOptions co = new ChromeOptions();
                        co.AddArguments("--Add Args Here");
                        IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(co);
                        return driver;
                    }
            }
            return null;
        }
```